# Widget para Eventos

Tags: css, eventos, widget

Boa noite,
Estou programando um site Html/css para uma banda. O cliente pediu para ter uma sessão com a agenda, eu achei o bandsintown manager, mas queria algum similar, onde o cliente muda as informações e aparecem no site automaticamente.

Pensei em fazer um iframe de um feed, já tentei com google docs, mas não tem como tirar as bordas do iframe.

Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Valeu

Answer (score 1):

Você não vai conseguir fazer isso só com HTML/CSS. Você precisa de uma linguagem de programação como php para salvar e exibir os dados dos eventos.

Aqui tem um tutorial completo até demais que pode te ajudar nessa parte do PHP https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/calendars-jquery-13-php-using-jquery-week-calendar-plugin-part-1. Você também pode procurar no google um plugin de calendário em php.

Se você for adicionar/remover datas "na mão" (você mesmo editar o código HTML cada vez que algo muda), existem diversos plugins de calendário com jQuery.